# Tomcat + RMI best way?

Tags: java, tomcat, rmi

What is the best way using RMI over tomcat?

Can i create global RMI-pool or one RMI connection for all my applications?

Comment: . Why you want to do like this way ..?

Comment: i need get data from stanbalone application  in my servlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a static class in a controller that wraps the RMI interface. RMI will pool your connections on the serverside, you don't need to worry about it in your Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Sample RMI

```
public interface Account 
          extends java.rmi.Remote { 
    public double balance(int accountNumber) 
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException; 

} 

public class AccountImpl 
    extends 
      java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject 
    implements Account { 
 public AccountImpl() 
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException { 
        super(); 
    } 

    public double add(int accountNumber) 
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException { 
        return 1000.0; 
    } 
}
```

Sample Servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
{

Account service=request.getSession()!=null ?(Account)request.getSession().getAttribute(loginService.ACCOUNT_SERVICE.name()):null;

service=service!=null?service:getService();
if(service!=null)
{
request.getSession().setAttribute(loginService.ACCOUNT_SERVICE.name(), service);
}
    }
    }

}
```